# Filtering Data in DataTbale ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

[image]enter image description here   *I have a problem with data filtration in the table. I would like the data in the filter list to remain intact for the applied filter and to be updated in the remaining ones. However, when I close the list of a given filter, the data is automatically updated there, I attach the code and a photo from the application*

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var savedFilters = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('savedFilters')) || {};
            var allFilterValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('allFilterValues')) || {};
    
            if ($.isEmptyObject(allFilterValues)) {
                initializeFilters();
            }
    
            $('#myTable thead th').each(function (index) {
                var arrow = $('<span/>').addClass('filter-arrow').html('&#9660;');
                $(this).append(arrow);
            });
    
            $('.filter-arrow').on('click', function () {
                var column = $(this).parent().index();
                showFilterContainer(column, $(this));
            });
    
            function showFilterContainer(column, arrow) {
                var filterContainer = $('#filter-container');
                if (!filterContainer.length) {
                    filterContainer = $('<div/>', {
                        id: 'filter-container',
                        css: {
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'background-color': '#fff',
                            'padding': '10px',
                            'border': '1px solid #ccc',
                            'box-shadow': '0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
                            'display': 'none',
                            'z-index': 1000
                        }
                    }).appendTo('body');
                } else {
                    filterContainer.empty();
                }
    
                var arrowOffset = arrow.offset();
                filterContainer.css({
                    'top': arrowOffset.top + 20,
                    'left': arrowOffset.left
                }).data('column', column).show();
    
                populateFilterOptions(filterContainer, column);
            }
    
            function populateFilterOptions(filterContainer, column) {
                var values = allFilterValues[column] || [];
                values.sort().forEach(function (cellValue) {
                    var listItem = $('<li/>');
                    var label = $('<label/>').text(cellValue);
                    var checkbox = $('<input/>', {
                        type: 'checkbox',
                        value: cellValue,
                        checked: savedFilters[column] && savedFilters[column].includes(cellValue)
                    }).on('change', function () {
                        updateFilters(column);
                    });
    
                    listItem.append(label.prepend(checkbox)).appendTo(filterContainer);
                });
            }
    
            function updateFilters(column) {
                var checkedValues = $('#filter-container input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();
    
                savedFilters[column] = checkedValues;
                localStorage.setItem('savedFilters', JSON.stringify(savedFilters));
    
                applyAllFilters();
    
                $('#myTable thead th').each(function (index) {
                    var columnValues = [];
                    $('#myTable tbody tr:visible').each(function () {
                        var cellValue = $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(index).text());
                        if (cellValue && !columnValues.includes(cellValue)) {
                            columnValues.push(cellValue);
                        }
                    });
                    allFilterValues[index] = columnValues;
                });
            }
    
            // Apply all filters
            function applyAllFilters() {
                $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
                    var row = $(this);
                    var isRowVisible = Object.keys(savedFilters).every(function (filterColumn) {
                        if (!savedFilters[filterColumn].length) return true; // No filter applied for this column
                        var cellValue = $.trim(row.find('td').eq(filterColumn).text());
                        return savedFilters[filterColumn].includes(cellValue);
                    });
                    row.toggle(isRowVisible);
                });
            }
    
            function initializeFilters() {
                $('#myTable thead th').each(function (index) {
                    var columnValues = [];
                    $('#myTable tbody tr').each(function () {
                        var cellValue = $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(index).text());
                        if (cellValue && !columnValues.includes(cellValue)) {
                            columnValues.push(cellValue);
                        }
                    });
                    allFilterValues[index] = columnValues;
                });
                localStorage.setItem('allFilterValues', JSON.stringify(allFilterValues));
            }
    
            $(document).on('click', function (e) {
                if (!$(e.target).closest('#filter-container').length && !$(e.target).is('.filter-arrow')) {
                    $('#filter-container').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>`
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use https://datatables.net/? It does what I think you want.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, not just code snippets that lack comntext.